# Select All the Rows which is having the same <td> attribute data-img_key="bull3"

Tags: javascript

Select All the Row Which is having the same `<td>` attribute`<td data-img_key="bull3">` . I want to select all **3 Star** Rows in this https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/  website. In the DOM console I'm getting the length of the rows which is having the **3Star** events like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('td[data-img_key="bull3"]').length
```

How can i get all the rows(**3start**) innerHTML data in the DOM console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `node.parentNode` to get access to the parentNode. Then just apply `innerText` or `innerHTML` whatever you want.

```
parents = [...document.querySelectorAll('td[data-img_key="bull3"]')].map(n => n.parentNode)
```

Comment: **Thank you so much for your effort**. I tried innerHTML after that, the console output is undefined, can you write full code?

Comment: `parents = [...document.querySelectorAll('td[data-img_key="bull3"]')].map(n => n.parentNode.innerHTML)
`

Here it is